# Display style for Internet explorer 8 and versions below

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to style my WordPress website to be displayed properly in Internet Explorer 8  and all versions below.

I have created a separate ie.css file but I am having problems styles to be read only when opened from IE.

In the head of my document I have included:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

When viewed from IE, the website is acting as this doesn't exist.

But when I insert this in to the head, all the styles appear in IE (that are meant for IE) but also in Chrome, Mozilla, etc..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen" />
```

Any advice?!

Comment: Well the `href` of the `link` is somewhat different between the non-working, and working, versions. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```